# Sinon stub of function giving error Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: typescript, chai, sinon, stub

There is a class method in a package as follows

```
async getPropertyAsync(name: string): Promise<string> {
    //do something
}
```

And another function in another package as follows

```
function getColor(prop: string) : string {
    switch(prop.toUpperCase()) {
        //do something
        default: return 'no_color';
    }
}
```

In my code I have

```
public async myFunction(): Promise<Something>{
    const colorProp = getColor(await myClass.getPropertyAsync('WHITE'));
    //do something
}
```

In my test I want to create stub of `getPropertyAsync`

```
const myClassStub = {} as MyClass;
myClassStub.myFunction = sandbox.stub().onCall(0).returns(Promise.resolve('FAKE_COLOR'));
const ret = myClassObj.myFunction();
```

At the last line above I get the following error while running my test

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')
```

I thought that the stub is not returning object type as `string`, so I tried the following two ways to explicitely state that the return type is a string.

```
let myStub = sandbox.stub(someObj, 'getPropertyAsync').resolves('FAKE_COLOR' as string);

let myStub = sandbox.stub(someObj, 'getPropertyAsync').returns(Promise.resolve('FAKE_COLOR' as string));
```

Both of the above did not work. They gave the same error.

Comment: What's `someObj`? Do you want to test `myFunction`? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example